# How to update records in mongo db using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My node js code,

```
  exports.updateprofiledetails = function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.body)
      var params = req.body;
      var item = 
      {
        firstname:params.firstname,
        lastname:params.lastname,
        phone:params.phone,
        street:params.street
      };console.log(item)
      var id = req.params.id;
      var record= db.collection('profile');
      record.updateOne({'_id':id},{$set:item},(err, result) => {
       if (err){ return console.log(err)
        }
          if(result){
              response = {status:'success',data:result};
            } else{
              response = {status:'fail',data:[]};
            }
          res.send(response);
      });

    };
```

From the above i give only 2(firstname,lastname) fields but then the remaining fields(phone.street) are assigned with null values.Can someone help me solve the problem.

Comment: What exactly you want the value of phone etc if it is not given?

Comment: Hi abdulbarik,I have a form with 4 fields to update but i update only 2 fields so that ithe remaining  2 fields are updated as null............

Comment: It'll save as null if you do not give any value or set default value in Schema if value is null

Comment: How does the complete document looks like in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to check and then set value that is only set value which sent from front end like

```
exports.updateprofiledetails = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  var params = req.body;
  var item = { }
  if(params.firstname)
    item.firstname = params.firstname;
  if(params.lastname)
    item.lastname = params.lastname;
  if(params.phone)
    item.phone = params.phone;
  if(params.street)
    item.street = params.street;
  console.log(item);
  var id = req.params.id;
  var record= db.collection('profile');
  record.updateOne({'_id':id},{$set:item},(err, result) => {
   if (err) { 
     return console.log(err)
   }
   if(result){
      response = {status:'success',data:result};
   } else{
      response = {status:'fail',data:[]};
   }
   res.send(response);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code.But you need to ensure the field **phone** ,**street** value exist in variable  **item**.Because your only give **firstname** & **lastname** from **params**.If your not giving the value to **phone** & **street** (via **params**) please remove the field from **item** variable.

Try the below code and Let me know what its returns

```
exports.updateprofiledetails = function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.body)
      var params = req.body;
      var item = 
      {
        firstname:params.firstname,
        lastname:params.lastname       
      };
      console.log(item) // Ensure this variable have data
      var id = req.params.id;
      var record= db.collection('profile');
      record.updateOne({'_id':id},{$set:item},(err, result) => {
       if (err){ return console.log(err)
        }
          if(result){
              response = {status:'success',data:result};
            } else{
              response = {status:'fail',data:[]};
            }
          res.send(response);
      });

    };
```